# Remove execute permission from uploaded folders and files

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

I am working on file and folder upload system and i want to add some security to it.

i have followed this [Article](https://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/12/28/8-basic-rules-to-implement-secure-file-uploads) , The security point number 6 on it says:

> **6. Keep tight control of permissions**
>
> Any uploaded file will be owned by the web server. But it only needs
>   read/write permission, not execute permissions. After the file is
>   downloaded, you could apply additional restrictions if this is
>   appropriate. Sometimes it can be helpful to remove the execute
>   permission from directories to prevent the server from enumerating
>   files.

How to apply that using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to upload a file to a remote server and then change the file to read only. Here is one option. Start by getting a File Object. After that you can set the access control then supply the access you want to provide.

It might be something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

private void SetFileAccess(string path)
    {
        var fileSecurity = new FileSecurity();
        var readRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("identityOfUser", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);
        var writeRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("identityOfUser", FileSystemRights.WriteData, AccessControlType.Allow);
        var noExecRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("identityOfUser", FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile, AccessControlType.Deny);
        fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(readRule);
        fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(writeRule);
        fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(noExecRule);
        File.SetAccessControl(path, fileSecurity);
    }
```

[MSDN Link to File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[MSDN Link to SetAccessControl Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[MSDN Link to File System Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?view=netframework-4.7.2)